# Qt - line edit input also causes push button action to occur

Tags: qt4

Pretty new to Qt and I ran into this behavior in an app I am writing so I created a very simple app to try and reproduce and it did.

click push button - information message appears
enter some text in line edit and hit enter - information box for text appears and then information for push button appears. I am very confused about why that is happening.

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
       ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"PB Test", "I have pushed the button");
}

void Dialog::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"LineEdit Test", "I entered text");
}
```

And here is dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
    class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_lineEdit_returnPressed();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QPushButton` is a default button, meaning it is activated every time Enter is pressed. If you want to disable this behavior you will need to subclass the `QLineEdit` and implement an `eventFilter` that filters the enter presses.

Comment: - I didn't know that it was a default, so your comment prompted me to re-read the Qt documentation about it and yep, that is exactly what they say, but there appears to be an easier solution to my problem and that is to uncheck autodefault in the pushbutton's properties and that worked just fine. So your answer got me on the right track. Thanks!